# Can I sum a calculation between two columns in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sum

What I would like to do is the following:

```
SELECT SUM(ABS(`number_x` - `number_y`)) AS `total_difference` FROM `table`
```

Where the table is as follow:

> id  |  number_x  |  number_y
>
> 1   |  4         |  2
>
> 2   |  3         |  2
>
> 3   |  2         |  4

So the answer should be:
(4 - 2 = 2) + (3 - 2 = 1) + (2 - 4 = 2) = 5

Can I do this in MySQL and how?

Thanks!

Comment: Errr.. just like that? Does your query not work?

Comment: Was anything wrong with your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you posted should work with no problem:

```
SELECT SUM(ABS(`number_x` - `number_y`)) AS `total_difference` 
FROM `table`
```

Or if you want to write it with a subquery like so:

```
SELECT SUM(diff) AS `total_difference` 
FROM
( 
    SELECT Id, ABS(number_x - number_y) diff
    FROM TableName
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(ABS(`number_x` - `number_y`)) AS `total_difference` FROM `table`
```

OR You can write other way, but i'll prefer above only

```
SELECT ABS(SUM(number_x) - SUM(number_y)) AS total_difference FROM table
```